# Vector SAT MATH 2

Tags: vectors

If the magnitudes of vectors a and b are 5 and 12, respectively, then the magnitude of vector (b-a) could NOT be:

a) 5

b) 7

c) 10

d) 12

e) 17

The answer is 5. But I am not sure which theorem I should use to go about this problem. Triangle inequality theorem? Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By triangle inequality:

$$|b|-|a|\le |a-b| \le |a|+|b|\to 7\le |a-b| \le 17$$

Comment: because the vectors, $a$, $b$ and $a-b$ form a triangle, or are colinear.

Comment: Is this clear??

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive approach: imagine the vector of length $12$ at a fixed position, and picture a vector of length $5$ swinging around the vector of length 12. In one of the extreme cases, the vector of length $5$ will be exactly aligned, so the difference will have length $7$. In the other extreme case, the vectors will be pointing in opposite directions, so the difference will have length $17$. Therefore, we see anything is possible between $[7,17]$.

Here's a more formal argument:

Another way of writing the magnitude of $\vec b - \vec a$ is

$$||\vec b - \vec a|| = \sqrt{\langle\vec b - \vec a, \vec b - \vec a\rangle}$$

where $\langle\vec x,\vec y\rangle$ is the dot product of $\vec x$ and $\vec y$.

Expanding the above using properties of dot products, we find
$$||\vec b - \vec a|| = \sqrt{\langle \vec b,\vec b \rangle + \langle \vec a, \vec a \rangle - 2 \langle \vec a, \vec b\rangle} = \sqrt{169 - 2 \langle \vec a, \vec b\rangle}$$
Because $-60 \le \langle \vec a ,\vec b \rangle \le 60$, we find that
$$7 \le ||\vec b - \vec a|| \le 17$$